# Error when resizing partition

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, windows-8.1, partitioning, ntfsresize

I need help with resizing a partition.

**What I have so far:**

I currently have a single hard drive with 3 partitions.

**Partition 1** has 11.4GB. It is my recovery partition and so I don't really want to change it in any way. It has 3Gb free

**Partition 2** has 160Gb and 22Gb. This had Windows 7 installed onto it. I need this partition to release or give away the free space to the partition 3.

**Partition 3** has only 14Gb and 1Gb free. I want to add the 22 or 20Gb of free space from partition 2 to this one. This is currently running Windows 8.1.

**What I have tried:**

- I have tried using windows tool to first `shrink the volume` so that I can extended to the one that I need it for however after shrink it tells me that **`I do not have enough space for this partition`**
- I have also tried using "Partition manager 15" to resize the two volumes straight however it told me to restart because the drives needed to accessed deeply. After boot it ran a long, what looked like scan,  which done absolutely nothing to it.

**My question is that is there a way to fix my first try or another method of doing this?**

**Note:** *I am actually unable to boot into the Windows 7 OS so I have to do everything in Windows 8.1. I do however have important files in the Windows 7 partition which I am able to access(So I don't want to format that).*

*Lastly I don't want to have to reinstall any version of windows again.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it used a different partition tool called Mini tools Partition Wizard